# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MAJOR_VERSION' - WordPress Plugin with Google Sheets Library

Tags: php, wordpress, google-sheets-api, guzzle

Whenever we have 2 Guzzle library WordPress plugins in same website then having incopatibility version issues for the Guzzle.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MAJOR_VERSION'

We need general solution that we can use for all the PHP version >=7.4 up to PHP latest verison 8.2

I have tried with general guzzle library but still getting same error.